# Modifying a dict during iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

What's going on below

```
>>> d = {0:0}
>>> for i in d:
...     del d[i]
...     d[i+1] = 0
...     print(i)
...     
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
>>>
```

Why does the iteration stop at 8 without any error?

Reproducible on both python2.7 and python 3.5.

Comment: mutating a dictionary during iteration results in undefined behaviour, I am curious about this too but *note to beginner programmers: don't do this.*

Comment: Just run the same `for` loop again to see other nice things...

Comment: This question was asked clearly just for the upvotes, which it deverses, btw.

Comment: What the actual f is going on here. Surely some kind of in joke

Comment: But apparently  {0:0, 1:1} does "something else" because it causes the code to blow up as expected. (This is sort of a dupe from my comment farther down.)

Comment: @PeterRowell that is because starting with `{0:0, 1:1}` makes the first iteration change the size of the dictionary which is restricted to try to prevent undefined behaviour like this from happening.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen But shouldn't be the size of `{0:0, 1:1}` also 8 - since this is the initial size?

Comment: Ok, I've just answered my own question.

Comment: the "size" of the dictionary within python standards is the `len` of the dictionary, no starting with 8 initial empty slots means nothing to how many of them are used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior originates from the key look up algorithm in cpython `static PyDictKeyEntry * lookdict(...)` as written in the [document](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L418):

> The basic lookup function used by all operations. This is based on
>   Algorithm D from Knuth Vol. 3, Sec. 6.4. ... The initial probe index
>   is computed as **hash mod the table size** (*which initially equals to 8*).

At the beginning of every for loop, the [`dict_next`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1369) function is called internally to resolve the address of the next element. The core of this function reads:

```cpp
value_ptr = &mp->ma_keys->dk_entries[i].me_value;
mask = DK_MASK(mp->ma_keys); // size of the array which stores the key values (ma_keys)
while (i <= mask && *value_ptr == NULL) { // skip NULL elements ahead 
    value_ptr = (PyObject **)(((char *)value_ptr) + offset);
    i++;
}
if (i > mask)
    return -1; // raise StopIteration
```

where `i` is the index of the C array which actually stores the values. As written above, the initial index of a key is calculated from `hash(key)%table_size`. The other element in the array is all set to `NULL` since the dict contains only one element in your test case.

Given the fact that `hash(i)==i` if `i` is an int, the memory layout of the dict in your example will be:

```
1st iter: [0,   NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL]; i=0
2nd iter: [NULL,1   ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL]; i=1
...
8th iter: [NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,7   ]; i=7
```

A more interesting test case would be:

```
def f(d):
  for i in d:
    del d[i]
    print hash(i)%8
    d[str(hash(i))]=0
f({0:0})       # outputs 0,1,6
f({'hello':0}) # outputs 5,7
f({'world':0}) # outputs 1
```

To conclude, the exiting condition of such loop is

```
hash(new_key)%8<=hash(old_key)%8
```

Answer (score 8):

The initial size of the key table in a dict is 8 elements. So `0`...`7` sets the 1st to 8th element and 8 sets the 1st element again, ending the loop.

#### [Source: Objects/dictobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L60)

> /* PyDict_MINSIZE_COMBINED is the starting size for any new, non-split
> dict. 8 allows dicts with no more than 5 active entries;
> experiments suggested this suffices for the majority of dicts
> (consisting mostly of usually-small dicts created to pass keyword
> arguments). Making this 8, rather than 4 reduces the number of
> resizes for most dictionaries, without any significant extra memory
> use.  */
>
> #define PyDict_MINSIZE_COMBINED 8

Comment: I was hoping something similar would be the case. Do you have a source to back what you're saying?

Comment: That may be true for `{0:0}`, but apparently not for `{0:0, 1:1}`! That causes the code to blow up as expected, but the original does not.

Comment: For {7:0} the loop just runs once. And for {9:0} it continue till 15.

Comment: Interesting! Although this is a classic case of undefined behaviour, a more perfect answer would say what makes those 8 iterations possible. Just because we set the next key in a table of 8 entries, python should not necessarily iterate 8 items. How exactly does the iterator on a dict behave? May be that would answer the above comment (`{9:0}`)..

Comment: I read @gdlmx's comment in [Rod Serling's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_Serling) voice.